# Best time to shoot supermoon

Tags: moon

I'm wanting to photograph the supermoon this weekend. It'll be my first time, so I've been studying up on how I should go about this, but as far as what time to shoot it is where I'm lost. The moon will be closest to earth at 6:32 a.m Sunday (I'm in CDT) Should I wait 'til then to shoot(if so what is the best way to expose for the moon since it's going to be pretty bright out) or should I do it earlier? I'm wanting to get a decent close up shot of the moon. Thanks in advance for your help!